# IBM Watson Assistant: How to get IAM key for v1 watson assistant services

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have an IBM Watson Assistant service with username and password format and now I want to create new credentials which should have IAM key for this service, Please let us know how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also migrate your Cloud Foundry service instance that uses un:pw to one that supports IAM. See [Migrating Watson services from Cloud Foundry](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=watson-migrate)

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two options to obtain IAM credentials for you IBM Watson Assistant service:

1. In the browser, go to the service dashboard by going to the [IBM Cloud resources portal](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources), locate your service instance, click on it and then in its dashboard on **Service credentials**. There you can [create new credentials](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-services-information#services-information-authenticate-api-calls).
2. In a terminal and using the [IBM Cloud CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud?topic=cloud-cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_service_key_create) you can use `ibmcloud resource service-key-create` to generate credentials.

Both options assume that you have [migrated your service instance from Cloud Foundry to IAM](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=watson-migrate#migrate-task).

Answer (score 0):

For creating a new credential, you can directly go to your watson assistant service/resource page, once there, on the left hand side, you would find **"Service Credentials"** **menu button**, there you would find an option to create a **"New credential"**, and once the credential is created, then the "apikey" of that "New credential", would actually be your **"IAM key"**, which can be viewed by clicking on the "View Credential" button highlighted below in the image.

*This is for IBM Watson Assistant V1 only.

[image]